# display next record from database [PHP / MYSQL]

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a database, with a table in it. In the table, there's only one "ID" field

```
ID
1
2
3
..
```

what I want to do is to display the ID individually on my page, starting from ID=1. and when I click a button, the next ID will be displayed (ID=2, ID=3, .. each button click)

So this is my code

```
 <?php
    ...
    $id = (isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 1);
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM id_table WHERE id>='$id' ORDER BY id ASC limit 2 ");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    ...

<form action="" method="POST">
   <h1 class="mb-3">
     <?php echo($row['id'])?>
   </h1>

   <button onclick="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Next</button>
</form>
```

ID is successfully displayed. But I've been struggling to make a working next button. 
If this is a bad coding, please let me know and point me in right direction, so I can fix my mistakes. Thank you in advance, have a great day!

Comment: You're looking for what is called "pagination".

Comment: Yes.. I've looked it up too, but I don't quite understand how to put it in the button, that's why i ask here. Also thank you for your response ^^

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway to address your question, you'll likely want to use AJAX for this, to get a decent user experience. The "next" button should trigger an AJAX request to a separate PHP script, which can get the next ID, and return it back to the javascript. The javascript can then add it to the page in the correct place. It might make sense if the AJAX request sends the ID it received previously, so that the server knows how to find the next one. This is similar to "load more"  functionality which you often see in websites.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! This code is only for practice, so i wrote it like that ^^ and thank you so much for the suggestion ! i'll make a safer code in the future :D

Comment: It seems that inserting a hidden input in your form element would help: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo($row['id'])?>">`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response ! I already found the solution by re-doing the code and make a pagination from start ^^ but i'll try your solution too. Thanks for the help !

Comment: "This code is only for practice, so i wrote it like that"...if I was you I would practice writing it safely now, instead of in the future. Then you will get into good habits from the beginning. Glad you resolved your issue anyway